# Solving a system of equations with specific range of coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I have define the following functions:

```
w[k_] := k*0.8 + (1 - k)*0.3

b[k_] := 0.3*Sqrt[k]
```

and I want to solve the following system of equations

`optimal = {0.5*x^(-1/2) == w[k]/(p + sP), D[b[k], k]/D[w[k], k] == x*(1 - r)/r}`

by calling the `Solve` function

`Solve[optimal, {x, k}, PositiveReals]`

However, $p>0$, $sP>0$  and $r\in[0,1]$. So, my question is how to tell `mathematica` to account for these constraints on the value of coefficients?

Comment: It does not answer your question but if your are using `Solve`, I would suggest adding `\\ Rationalize` after the definition of `optimal`.

Comment: Also, the condition can be simplified. If $p$ and $sP$ are positive, since $x^(-1/2)>0$, `w[k]` has to be positive too, `Reduce[w[k] > 0 // Rationalize]` returns `k > -(3/5)`.

Comment: `w[k]` is always positive, since $k\in[0,1]$

Comment: `w[k_] = k*0.8 + (1 - k) 0.3 // Rationalize;
b[k_] = Rationalize@0.3*Sqrt[k] // Rationalize;
optimal = {0.5*x^(-1/2) == w[k]/(p + sP), 
    D[b[k], k]/D[w[k], k] == x*(1 - r)/r, x > 0, k > 0, p > 0, sp > 0,
     0 < r < 1} // Rationalize;
Reduce[optimal, {x, k}, Reals]`